# The month before the previous month vs two months ago

Tags: conjunctions

Considering the following sentence - "Percentage change in the number of visitors in the previous month compared to two months ago". Considering the current month as December, would "two months ago" mean October (intended) or September (not intended) in this case. Should I change "two months ago" to "the month before that" to achieve the intended meaning?

Comment: There you have it.

Comment: The phrase "two months ago" indicates a moment in time, not a period lasting a month. Why not *say* November and October?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, is the original sentence correct or does it need to be amended?

Comment: @Rosie F, this description is going to be used in an automated monthly report with the date ranges naturally changing every month.

Comment: @Math101 Thank you for that additional context. But my question still stands. An app which can automatically produce the report for a specified month can automatically insert the appropriate month names into the appropriate places.

Comment: You asked "Should I change" and the answer is, well, only if you want to be clear. Also, how is September two months before December, unless December is -1?

Comment: @Rosie F,  apparently not the one we are using..

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, my concern was that "two months ago" is this context could mean two months before the previous month not two months before this month. The previous month being November, and two months before that being September. Hopefully, that makes sense and I am not causing unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I would call it the "penulti-month"

Comment: "ago" is generally relative to the current time. If you want to be relative to a time you specified, you would say "previous", "earlier", or "prior".

Comment: "Two months ago" means about 60 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

We have definitions :

> previous = going before in time or order : Prior
>
> [Merriam Webster] (https://www.merriam-webster.co>m/dictionary/previous)

> ago = earlier than the present time
>
> [Merriam Webster] (https://www.merriam-webster.co>m/dictionary/ago)

Hence we may interpret the sentence as follows. My interpretation is in {}.

*Percentage change in the number of visitors in the previous* {compared to the month of reading, which is presumably the present month} *month compared to two months ago* {from the present date}.

If the present month is December, this gives us:

*Percentage change in the number of visitors in the previous month* {= November} *compared to two months ago* {= October}.

Another possibility might be that a month has been mentioned earlier. In this case we would have:

*Percentage change in the number of visitors in the previous* {to the one that has already been mentioned} *month compared to two months ago* {from the present date}.

As no month has been mentioned in your example, this interpretation does not apply.